# Replace java operators by methods in bytecode using javassist

Tags: java, bytecode, javassist, java-bytecode-asm, bytecode-manipulation

### My Goal

To be able to detect when, at runtime, a comparison is made (or any other operation like, *, - , /, >, < ,...

This should be achieved to edit the bytecode of a class using Javassist or ow2 ASM

### What must be achieved

This code

```
public class Test{

    public void m(){

        if(a>2){
        //blablabla         
        }

    }  

}
```

Has to become

```
public class Test{

    public void m(){

        if(someExternalClass.greaterThan(a,2)){
            //blalbla           
    }

    }

}
```

The greaterThan will return exactly the same result as '>' but will also be used the save the amount of comparisons
The external class will then be notified everytime a comparison has been made

### Extra note

It has to be done everywhere there is an operation. So not only in if statements.

This means

```
int a = c+d;
```

must also become

```
int a = someExternalClass.add(c,d);
```

Do you have any suggestions on how I can achieve this with Javassist or other libraries.

I guess it'll have something to do with OpCodes like IFLT, IFGT

Comment: I would replace `if(a>2)` with `someExternalClass.counter++; if(a>2)`

Comment: @PeterLawrey Not entirely. Because in my final code every class will have an identifier. So the actual code would be
`someExternalClass.greaterThan(Identifier,a,2)`

And also, the code would stop working normally (it is required that the working of the algorithm remains unchanged)

Comment: @PeterLawrey I added an extra example above (see 'Extra Note')

Comment: Either way it will work or not. A method call is more flexible.  Have you tried ASM for this?

Comment: @PeterLawrey I did look into that. And normally I think it should be able to the trick. But it was quite complex, so I first searched for something more high level. Do you have any suggestions what parts of ASM I certainly have to study?

Comment: You can override the http://asm.ow2.org/asm33/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/MethodVisitor.html and add additional visits for the extra code you want.

Answer (score 2):

It might be easier to do this with the source code or at compile time with an annotation processor. For the annotation processor approach you could use [Juast](https://bitbucket.org/amelentev/juast/wiki/Home) or [Lombok](http://projectlombok.org/).

[OperatorOverload](https://bitbucket.org/amelentev/juast/src/d4d681035da6/processors/src/main/java/juast/processors/OperatorOverload.java) seems to almost do what you want, it replaces binary expressions with method calls.

Answer (score 2):

This clever hack: http://www.jroller.com/eu/entry/operation_overloading_in_java can give you a hint. The original idea is to give some operator overloading support to Java. You are not doing the exact same thing, but it is somewhat related.